# How do I have an optional enum?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, jsonschema

Using draft "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema" with Helm.

I'm not understanding the behavior of enum. I want to have a non required enum. By non-required that should mean if the enum is not specified it's ignored, but if it is specified it should be validated.

But this does not work:

```
"myobj": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "optionalEnum": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "aaa",
            "enum": [
                "aaa",
                "bbb",
                "ccc"
            ]
        }...
```

If I don't specify `optionalEnum` I get an error saying `optionalEnum must be one of the following: "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"`

Shouldn't it just ignore it? I don't want to add `null` as an enum value because I want to prevent the user from setting it to null. Is there a way to say only if the property is set apply the enum validation to it?

Perhaps jsonschema makes no distinction between an "unset" and an empty/null property?

Comment: pure jsonschema behaves exactly as you expect it to: if you omit `optionalEnums` it validates fine. You can play around in https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ to test it out. Can you double check your example and potentially present it with more context? Alternatively, the Helm validator doesn't behave according to the standard.

Comment: Yup looks like its working as I would expect: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/AXM6rT4E. Maybe the implementation has a bug or optionalEnum is somehow leaking in. I will have to confirm which it is.

Comment: It sounds like there's a bug with the implementation. Did you file an issue in a public repo as a result of this? JSON Schema is constraints based, and `properties` value object subscheams are only applied IF there's a matching key, as you suposesed.